# Storage Access Framework - getting file attributes rwx, c++ stat replacement

Tags: android, c++, attributes, stat, storage-access-framework

I have a native c++ application. I migrate it to new google's storage restrictions. User grants read/write permissions on some folder with files inside. Somehow has happened that some files inside have not "rwx" attributes, they only have read flags.

On java side I open a file for write and send native file descriptor to c++:

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/9C33-6BBD%3AGames/document/9C33-6BBD%3AGames%2Fdos%2FDAVE2%2FINTRO.DD2

    ParcelFileDescriptor fd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "rw");
int nativeFD = fd.detachFd();
```

I get file uris querying the the root uri which was obtained from picker using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
   context.startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
```

---

```
    DocumentFile documentDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, safUri);
    Uri uri = documentDir.getUri();

    final Uri childrenUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(uri, DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri));

    double t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        c = getContentResolver().query(childrenUri, new String[] {
                DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID,
                DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME,
                DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE
        }, null, null, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            final String documentId = c.getString(0);
            final String documentName = c.getString(1);
            final Uri documentUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(uri, documentId);

            folderContent.append(documentName + "\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {
            try {
                c.close();
            } catch (RuntimeException rethrown) {
                throw rethrown;
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
```

However, it crashes if I do openFileDescriptor on a file with readonly flags.

Previously, I did "stat" (on c++ side) on this file and tested `stat.st_mode` & `S_IWUSR`.

How should I replace this test using SAF? I need something like java File.canWrite()

Comment: We do not see you using SAF.

Comment: I updated my question, hope it will be clear

Comment: Sorry, i see nothing updated and there is still no SAF.

Comment: Storage Access Framework is framework for working with files in scoped storage. Please stop spamming my question in hunt of points, everyone familiar with c++ and scoped storage on android understands my question.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with scoped storage and SAF also has nothing to do with scoped storage. So if you want help than post the relevant SAF code to begin with.

Comment: I will not learn you how to work with c++ fopen, fdopen in scoped storage. However, if you forget that I added SAF to tags, are you able help me how to detect that file under uri has write able flags?

Comment: I have no idea where your uri comes from. So for the third time: Show your SAF code. Make it clear how you get your uri.

Comment: I get file uris querying the the root uri which was obtained from picker using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. I updated question with code

Comment: Sorry, i cannot follow your code. First there is no onActivityResult for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. Second you suggested that you obtained the file uri under java. I do not see that. Third: it is unclear where you call openFileDescriptor(). How could anybody help you if it is unclear what you do?

Comment: Should I paste here my application? Many times is simple question way understandable than long code. For you I screwed my question, so I added how I obtain uri, how I list uri to get files list. On these uris I call openFileDescriptor. That's all.

Comment: You could save a lot of talk here and a lot of code if you just picked one file with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: I cannot use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. Or you mean it only for example?

Comment: Of course. Just for testing. And choose the file that gives problems. And tell what kind of file it is and which app created the file. I have never seen that files obtained with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE or ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT were not writable if in onActivityResult you obtained WRITE permission. You can directly check that permission there for that file if you choose one file.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand. Yes, it is truth. I am on android 11, it throws exception. Seems like granting permission on folder grants access, but further it reacts on file own permissions. I don't choose one file. I work on emulator, I need fast access, can't pick file by file. All ways how to detect file attributes what I found are made for absolute file path, this is not possible in scoped storage

Comment: Again: just for testing choose one file. And its time you post the relevant exception lines from the logcat as you should show us what happens. You cannot grant access to a folder. The only thing you can do is let the user pick a folder and then see if you get READ and or WRITE access. If that is granted to you. You cannot grant anything.

Comment: Well, I will simulate it and post the exception.

Comment: No, I am unable to change file attributes to read only, android blocks me. I don't have now rooted device. Maybe I can try it in android emulator.

Comment: No, I don't know how it happen. These files were read-only. Every attempt to make read-only files on my android devices now failed, files have always at least rw. I can't provide error message.